# Msg 102, Level15, State 1, Line 16 INSERT based on SELECT

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have looked at the various other posts about this error message and tried their solutions. Nothing seems to fix my problem. My post pretty much describes what I'm trying to do; I want to create a new shop in my database with the same fields as an existing shop.

This is my code.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ElementDescriptions] (
[FieldName]
, [DisplayName]
, [Required]
, [DataType]
, [SortOrder]
, [ElementID]
, [Description]
, [Lookup]
, [UIType]
, [RequiredForNew]
, [RequiredForReconditioned]
, [RequredForSecondhand]
, [ShopCode])
    SELECT ([FieldName]
    , [DisplayName]
, [Required]
    , [DataType]
, [SortOrder]
, [ElementID]
, [Description]
, [Lookup]
, [UIType]
, [RequiredForNew]
, [RequiredForReconditioned]
, [RequredForSecondhand]
, 'NEWSHOP')
FROM [dbo].[ElementDescriptions]
WHERE [AARShopCode] = 'OLDSHOP'
```

My error says it's near     ','.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have parentheses around the select list.

```
INSERT dbo.table(columns) SELECT (columns) FROM ...
```

Should be:

```
INSERT dbo.table(columns) SELECT  columns  FROM ...
---------------------------------^-------^
```